# "This model's maximum context length is 4097 tokens" but tiktoken claims my prompt is far below the token limit

Tags: node.js, token, openai-api, chatgpt-api

Using Node.js.  I am submitting an array of messages to ChatGPT as a prompt via the typical OpenAI API route of:

```
const completion = await this.openai.chat.completions.create({
            messages: messages,
            model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo'
            });
```

Before submitting, I count the tokens using `tiktoken` using the following class method `TokenCounter.countFromUserMessages()`:

```
import {get_encoding, encoding_for_model} from 'tiktoken';

class TokenCounter{

    constructor(){
        this.enc = get_encoding('cl100k_base');
    }
       
    countFromUserMessages(userMessages){
        const initialValue = 0;
        const result = userMessages.reduce((accumulator,currentValue) => {
            const messageTokenCount = this.enc.encode(currentValue.content).length;
            return accumulator + messageTokenCount;
        },initialValue);
        return result;
    }
}
export default TokenCounter;
```

My understanding is that `this.enc.encode(currentValue.content).length` should give a count of the number of tokens in each message, because `enc.encode()` converts a string to an array of tokens.

I submitted a message array calculated at 2097 tokens, and OpenAI responded with the error:

```
This model's maximum context length is 4097 tokens. However, your messages resulted in 4337 tokens. Please reduce the length of the messages.
```

While it's possible that OpenAI generated a response that was 2000+ tokens, this is unlikely because the message array includes responses from ChatGPT earlier in the conversation (being submitted to give ChatGPT context since the API is stateless), and ChatGPT's responses are all consistently measured at ~100-300 tokens.  Note that one of the messages in the array is a system message designed to limit the size of ChatGPT's response:

```
{
 role: 'system',
 content: 'Your response must be 2000 characters or less.'
}
```

The only thing I can think of is that `tiktoken`'s `enc.encode()` function is severely undercounting the tokens, but the module is supposedly a direct port of OpenAI's Python-based `tiktoken` library.

So: why am I running into the token limit when submitting so few tokens in my prompt?

Comment: Confirmed that `tiktoken`'s count is lower than OpenAI's; more discussion [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/OpenAI/comments/173lnli/comment/k43xugv/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)